Unable to InferSchema with Databricks SQL
When I attempt to create a table with Databricks SQL I get the error:

AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.

%sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtabletable USING csv OPTIONS (path "abfss://root@axxxxxadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/mnt/lake2/RAW/devices.csv",inferSchema 'True', header 'True');

However, I'm able to read the file using PySpark:
df = (spark.read      
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv('/mnt/lake2/RAW/devices.csv')
)

I am working with Azure Databricks. I think the issue has something to do with Unity Catalog, but not sure.


AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.

According to the MS document Databricks recommends the read_files table-valued function for SQL users to read CSV files. read_files is available in Databricks Runtime 13.3 LTS and above.
If you use SQL to read CSV data directly without using temporary views or read_files, the following limitations apply:

You can’t  specify data source options.

You can’t  specify the schema  for the data.


That may be the reason for getting the above error while reading CSV files directly in SQL. Instead, use the following SQL code to read the CSV file:
%sql
CREATE TABLE employees AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  read_files(
    '/mnt/root/lake2/RAW/employees.csv',
    header => "True"
  );

You will be able to create a table and query the table successfully as shown below:


As mentioned in the Azure Databricks SQL Language Manual for CREATE TABLE [USING] command:

If you do not define columns the table schema you must specify either AS query or LOCATION.

Cryptic usage of grammar but what they are trying to say is - "Use either AS query or LOCATION clause if you don't want to define columns manually."
Try the following query instead:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtabletable 
USING CSV LOCATION 'abfss://root@axxxxxadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/mnt/lake2/RAW/devices.csv'
OPTIONS (header 'true', inferSchema 'true');

Adding to this as mentioned here:

For any data_source other than DELTA you must also specify a LOCATION unless the table catalog is hive_metastore.

Also keep in mind that:

Specifying a location makes the table an external table.

Update:
I have added the OPTIONS clause in the code above. I'll recommend you check further if setting different options related to CSV files helps with this error.
One of the options that seem related to your query is enforceSchema and similarly, you can test others as well.

Hi @Vikas, thanks for getting in touch. I tried your suggestion CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtabletable USING CSV LOCATION 'abfss://root@axxxxxadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/mnt/lake2/RAW/devices.csv'; but I still got the error AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.

How about AS query? Same error for that as well? If yes, then perhaps you need to manually specify the schema as pointed out by the error message.

Or I would recommend you to go through he list of options for CSV and see if it helps. I noticed that in my answer I didn't include any options. I'll update it.
